# How to replace the window to blank or close?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  function CloseWindow() {
         self.close();
         window.location.replace("http://google.com");
      }
```

It close the window tab for chrome and IE but it redirects to 'google' tab for Mozilla.How to replace it to empty or close the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To close a window, use

```
window.close();
```

Note that [this will only work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) in windows opened programmatically, ie via `window.open`.

To redirect to an empty page, use

```
location.replace("about:blank");
```

Comment: can we close the window tab?

Comment: @josna - Yes, `window.close` will close the current tab/window if opened by a script.

Comment: @josna - This should work for all browsers that support JS.

Comment: 'Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.' this error shows in Mozilla

Comment: @josna - That means your window was not opened by a script, as mentioned in the answer itself. All browsers behave the same.

Comment: yes.like chrome and IE ,i have to close the window in Mozilla.Thats the thing i didn't get.:(

Comment: @josna - If your window is not opened a script, you cannot close it programmatically in every single browser - Chrome, IE, Firefox. (Though in IE it will prompt the user if s/he wants to close it.) It won't work on Chrome; it won't work on Firefox. They all behave the same.